# How to get URL from a JSON object part

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable in Javascript like it-

```
var uri = "https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?size=100x100&zoom=11&center=22.816667,89.55";
```

So What I need is it converted like-

```
var uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=100x100&zoom=11&center=22.816667,89.55";
```

What I have done is-

```
var uri = "https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?size=100x100&zoom=11&center=22.816667,89.55";


var uri_dec = JSON.stringify(uri);
```

And Get

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=100x100&zoom=11¢er=22.816667,89.55

So problem is I am getting **¢er** insted of **&center**.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: The two strings you have are identical. They are just expressed differently in JS literals. Your attempt to convert it is pointless. http://jsbin.com/xohimugixu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I don't understand why you think `JSON.stringify` would convert it in that way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
var uri_dec = decodeURI(uri);
```

**edit**

I thought you want to decode an already encoded URI, but after reading Quentin's comment I'm not sure anymore. So use the above example if you want to decode an already uri-encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are rendering it in HTML as I see it. The `&cent` is rendered as the USD cent symbol, if you want to escape it, use `&amp;` instead of the simple `&`.